# Is there a way to get to list a query of an object under a primary key id? the object itself has foreignkey referenced on the main table in aspnetcore

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq, repository

I have two two tables 'seller and vehicle table' and i want to get list of vehicle created by a seller. the seller table has primary key Id and a foreign key reference to vehicle 'VehicleId', the seller through a sellerid should be able to get list of vehicle created by itself.
i mean a sellerid should get the list of vehicle he/she has created.

Please check the code i have tried in the SellerRepository

This is seller table

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Models
{
    public class Seller
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int VehicleId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("VehicleId")]
        public Vehicle Vehicle { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Invalid Email ID")]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string SellerEmail { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public string Sex { get; set; }
        public string Company { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public int SellerPhone { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public int PhoneNo2 { get; set; }
        public string PostalCode { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Profile Image")]
        [StringLength(100)]
        public string ProfileImagePath { get; set; }

    }
}
```

This is Vehicle table

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Utility.Extensions;

namespace Models
{
    public class Vehicle
    {
        
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Make Make { get; set; }
        [RegularExpression("^[1-9]*$", ErrorMessage = "Select Make")]
        public int MakeID { get; set; }
        public Model Model { get; set; }
        [RegularExpression("^[1-9]*$", ErrorMessage = "Select Model")]
        public int ModelID { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Provide Year")]        
        [YearRangeTillDate(2000,ErrorMessage = "Not with in the valid Year range")]
        public int Year { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter Mileage")]
        [Range(1,int.MaxValue,ErrorMessage ="Not with in the valid mileage range")]
        public int Mileage { get; set; }

        
        public string Features { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage ="Provide Seller Name")]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string SellerName { get; set; }

        [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage ="Invalid Email ID")]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public Seller SellerEmail { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Provide Phone No.")]
        [Phone]
        [StringLength(15)]
        public Seller SellerPhone { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Provide Price")]
         [Range(1, 999999999, ErrorMessage = "Not with in the valid price range")]
        public int Price { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(10)]
        [RegularExpression("^[a-zA-Z]*$", ErrorMessage ="Select Currency")]       
        public string Currency { get; set; }

        [Display(Name ="Image File")]
        [StringLength(100)]
        public string ImagePath { get; set; }

    }
}
```

ISellerRepository.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Persistence.Repository.IRepository
{
    public interface ISellerRepository : IRepository<Seller>
    {
        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetModelListForDropDown();
       // void Update(Seller model);
        Task<bool> SellerOwnsVehicleAsync(int sellerId, int vehicleId);

    }
}
```

SellerRepository to get list of vehicle created by seller

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Models;
using Persistence.Repository.IRepository;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Persistence.Repository
{
    public class SellerRepository : Repository<Seller>, ISellerRepository
    {
        private readonly AutoServDbContext _db;
        public SellerRepository(AutoServDbContext db) : base (db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetModelListForDropDown()
        {
            return _db.Sellers.Select(i => new SelectListItem()
            {
                Text = i.Name,
                Value = i.Id.ToString()
            });
        }

        public async Task<bool> SellerOwnsVehicleAsync(int sellerId, int vehicleId)
        {
            var seller = await _db.Sellers.AsNoTracking().SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id ==     sellerId);

            if (seller == null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            if (seller.VehicleId != vehicleId)
            {
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Vehicle.SellerEmail` and `Vehicle.SellerPhone` both return an instance of `Seller` in this model. The relationship between `Vehicle` and `Seller` doesn't look like it is properly defined.  This might be the source of your issues. Your request sounds like you are expecting `Seller` to have multiple `Vehicle`... probably in a property called `Vehicles`, but you have not provided for that in your model.

Comment: I think the same. You mentioned multiple Vehicles but you define just one Vehicle in Seller model instead of List: 

[ForeignKey("VehicleId")]
public Vehicle Vehicle { get; set; }

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your model, `Seller` has a single `Vehicle` navigation property, but `Vehicle` has two navigation properties that link back to potentially *different* `Seller` records: `SellerEmail` and `SellerPhone`.

> the seller through a sellerid should be able to get list of vehicle created by itself

Your request states that a given `Seller` can have multiple `Vehicle` records, but your model does not permit this.

> Your current model for `Vehicle` resembles a *Vehicle Create or Summary DTO*, but not necessarily how the data would actually be stored in the database, or your repository. The structure itself is not invalid, but it does not represent a *normal form* for data storage.

First step, change the relationship in your model, take out the `VehicleId` and `Vehicle` from the the `Seller`, replace this with a collection property:
***NOTE:** I have omitted the properties that can remain unchanged*

```
public class Seller
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    //[Required]
    //public int VehicleId { get; set; }
    //[ForeignKey("VehicleId")]
    //public Vehicle Vehicle { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Vehicle> Vehicles { get; set; } = new HashSet<Vehicle>();
    
    ...
}
```

Then make the reverse change in `Vehicle`, provide the link back to the `Seller`. In this modified *Model*, each `Vehicle` can have a single `Seller`.

```
public class Vehicle
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Make Make { get; set; }
    [RegularExpression("^[1-9]*$", ErrorMessage = "Select Make")]
    public int MakeID { get; set; }
    public Model Model { get; set; }
    [RegularExpression("^[1-9]*$", ErrorMessage = "Select Model")]
    public int ModelID { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Provide Year")]        
    [YearRangeTillDate(2000,ErrorMessage = "Not with in the valid Year range")]
    public int Year { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter Mileage")]
    [Range(1,int.MaxValue,ErrorMessage ="Not with in the valid mileage range")]
    public int Mileage { get; set; }

    
    public string Features { get; set; }

    // Question: is this necessary, now that we have a Seller
    //[Required(ErrorMessage ="Provide Seller Name")]
    //[StringLength(50)]
    //public string SellerName { get; set; }

    // Removing, no longer relevant
    //[EmailAddress(ErrorMessage ="Invalid Email ID")]
    //[StringLength(50)]
    //public Seller SellerEmail { get; set; }

    // Removing, no longer relevant
    //[Required(ErrorMessage = "Provide Phone No.")]
    //[Phone]
    //[StringLength(15)]
    //public Seller SellerPhone { get; set; }

    public Seller Seller { get; set}
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Provide Seller")]
    public int SellerID { get; set}

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Provide Price")]
     [Range(1, 999999999, ErrorMessage = "Not with in the valid price range")]
    public int Price { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(10)]
    [RegularExpression("^[a-zA-Z]*$", ErrorMessage ="Select Currency")]       
    public string Currency { get; set; }

    [Display(Name ="Image File")]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string ImagePath { get; set; }

}
```

Then we can just expose the Vehicles as their own endpoint from the `SellerRepository`:

```
public IQueryable<Vehicle> VehiclesAsync(int sellerId)
{
    var vehicles = _db.Vehicles.AsNoTracking().Where(x => x.SellerId == sellerId);

    return vehicles;
}
```

or you could add a similar endpoint to the `VehicleRespository`:

```
public async IQueryable<Vehicle> BySellerAsync(int sellerId)
{
    var vehicles = _db.Vehicles.AsNoTracking().Where(x => x.SellerId == sellerId);

    return vehicles;
}
```

With this new structure the reverse filter, from the `_db.Sellers` DbSet would also work:

```
_db.Sellers.Where(s => s.Id == sellerId).SelectMany(s => s.Vehicles);
```

---

If you wanted to support a model where there is a M:N relationship between `Seller` and `Vehicle`, then that can also be achieved, that would allow a `Vehicle` to have multiple owners, one might suggest with a period of time defined for each owner record, however that would involve an additional table t manage the relationship.

Comment: Thanks Chris, i'd thought of using ICollection of Vehicle on my Seller Model before, am just not sure maybe it will work. And concerning SellerEmail and SellerPhone, it has no relationship with seller table i should'nt have add Seller as prefix to the property name. Thanks

Comment: Its the data type of the properties, not the name of them that had me concerned. You had two properties that both return a `Seller` reference, it is redundant, but also confusing, the classes would actually allow you to link two different `Seller` records to the same `Vehicle` and I doubt that was your intention. Having a collection of `Vehicle` seems logical to me, it is very common for these models and repositories to expose links to navigation records and collections. IDK but there is something about _Repository_ "how to" documents that make this connection harder to make for some reason.